# html scraping POST information using aps.net and htmlAgility

Tags: asp.net, post, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Im working on a web-scraping project i know how to get certain data from target page through HtmlAgilityPack. But i dont know what to send in the Post information of that page. The page is not sending any information through querystring. There are three textboxes in that page, two checkboxes and a search button

when i inspect the button with firebug it gives following information

```
<img border="0" align="top" onclick="javascript:PVO_PId_Search(
                document.ProtocolForm.searchplt,
                document.ProtocolForm.towcheck.checked,
                document.ProtocolForm.collateralcheck.checked,
                document.ProtocolForm.selState[document.ProtocolForm.selState.selectedIndex].value,
                document.ProtocolForm.selPltType[document.ProtocolForm.selPltType.selectedIndex].value)" onmouseout="this.className='flyOut'" onmouseover="this.className='flyOver'" alt="Search" value="PSearch" name="PSearch" onload="javascript:updateButtonWithOneTxtbox(document.ProtocolForm.searchplt,this,'v_images/Search_button.gif','v_images/Search_button_grey.gif');" src="v_images/Search_button.gif" class="flyOut">
```

Now my question is, Is there any tool or firefox addin available which i can use and monitor (or debug) what kind of Post information it is passing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in Web Developer tools in Chrome and/or Safari, etc to inspect all http request/responses between your client (browser) and the (server) web site. You'll see it in the *NETWORK* inspector tools.

However, unless it's your site, or some worthy educational experiment, whether or not you can actually **spoof** (yes, that's what it really amounts to) a POST (or GET) to the site depends on whether or not it has some built in protections/validations that protect it from such attempts.

Update:

Just fire up **Chrome** and (on Windows) `CTRL+SHIFT+I` (Safari, its `CTRL+ALT+I`) and you should see the NETWORK INSPECTOR:
[image]

Update 2:
And just for reference, if you want network inspection that isn't dependent on a browser, [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is always part of my personal tool kit.

Comment: well what im trying is just legal and with no restrictions. Can you name the network inpector tools.